# C#でウインドウ表示

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
class part02 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    static void Main()
    {
    //  文字の出力
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(new part02());
```

としているんですが、[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

とエラーが出ます。解決方法を教えて下さい。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.Windows.Forms.Form`のうち`Windows`で警告が出ず`Forms`が警告されている点が気になります。この現象は`PresentationFramework.dll`等を参照していることを意味します。

C#でGUIを実現するには

- [System.Windows.Forms名前空間](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.windows.forms(v=vs.110).aspx)のWinForms
- [System.Windows.Controls名前空間](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.windows.controls(v=vs.110).aspx)のWPF

の２系統があります。両者を混在させることも可能ではありますが、敷居が高いのでどちらかのみを選択することをお勧めします。その上でWinFormsを選択されるのであれば、エラーメッセージの通りですので`System.Windows.Forms.dll`を参照に追加してください。

なお、`Form`派生クラスに`Main()`メソッドを記述する方法は15年ほど前VS.NET 2002 / 2003の頃のものですので、せめてVS2005以降、できればVS2010以降を対象としたドキュメントを参照されることをお勧めします。

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.dllを参照するには、どこにどう記述すればよろしいのでしょうか？

Comment: @長谷川諒 さん、プロジェクトメニューにあります。ただし、他にも設定すべき点がありますので、Windowsフォームアプリケーション プロジェクトを新規に作り直すことをお勧めします。

Comment: そうできたらいいのですが、https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dU9D85LgLIw　この講座を見ながらやっているんですよ

Comment: @長谷川諒 さん、質問文にはそのような記載はありませんでしたので、後出しされても答えに含めようがありません。また当該動画のタイトルを見ましたが「メモ帳で」とありますので、これに従うべきです。

Comment: 「メモ帳で」でも、動画作成者は、Visual Studioを使ってもいいとおっしゃておりましたので使ってたのですが・・・

Comment: @長谷川諒 さん、であれば動画に従えばよいのではありませんか？ Visual Studioの表示に関わらずプログラムを完成させられる…かもしれません。

Comment: そうですね、もう少し考えます。ありがとうございました。

Comment: @長谷川諒 さん、動画の3:11辺りの操作を行えばエラーは出ないはずです。Visual Studioの表示は「メモ帳代わりに使う」という正しくない操作に起因するものですので気にしなくてもいいです。

Answer (score 0):

> 動画作成者は、Visual Studioを使ってもいいとおっしゃておりましたので

ということなら、Visual Studio を使うこと自体は問題ないんでしょうけど、すでに指摘されているとおり、作成済みのプロジェクト構成を Windows Forms から WPF に変更するのは初学者にはなかなか難しいです。

手間を惜しまず、WPF プロジェクトを新規に作成してやり直すことをお勧めします。

Answer (score 0):

私は下のようにしたらできましたよ。

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class 自分の好きな名前 : Form
{
  static void Main()
  {　//ほんとはこのカッコは２文字分あいてるよ
    Application.Run(new classの名前());
  } //ここも
}
```